# Mensagem de Erro do Compilador: CS0433

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-profile

Alguém pode me ajudar com esse erro, estou tentando criar um perfil com o ProfileCommon

> Erro de Compilação
>
> Descrição: Erro ao compilar um recurso necessário para atender esta
>   solicitação. Examine os detalhes específicos do erro e modifique o
>   código fonte apropriadamente.
>
> Mensagem de Erro do Compilador: CS0433: O tipo 'ProfileCommon' existe
>   tanto em 'c:\Users\marconibarroso.\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\e457865f\cc134d14\assembly\dl3\f4208480\dca737e7_71d6cf01\CRM
>   Onlline.DLL' como em
>   'c:\Users\marconibarroso.\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\e457865f\cc134d14\App_Code.ucs9f3oh.dll'

Meu código

```
public class ProfileCommon : ProfileBase
{
    public virtual string UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("UserId")));
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue("UserId", value);
        }
    }

    public virtual string Nome
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("Nome")));
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue("Nome", value);
        }
    }

    public virtual string TipoPermissao
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("TipoPermissao")));
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue("TipoPermissao", value);
        }
    }

    public virtual string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("Email")));
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue("Email", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @OnoSendai eu acho que esse erro pode ser gerado porque eu tenho 2 visual studio, 2010 e 2012. São aplicações diferentes mais as duas usam o mesmo conceito! Você sabe algo a respeito do erro?

Comment: Me parece que as duas classes possuem a mesma identificação, @Marconi - mesmo namespace, mesmo nome. O compilador não consegue decidir qual carregar. Eu não tenho como oferecer uma solução sem saber mais a respeito do framework em questão, mas talvez seja o caso de você herdar da classe básica ou dar outro nome a ela.

Comment: Olha eu acho que seria isso mesmo, porque troquei o nome ele rodou meu projeto, porem ele fala ainda que  Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'ProfileCommon' no tipo 'ProfileComm'. Mais em casa verei isso direito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude o nome da classe:

```
public class MeuProfileCommon : ProfileBase { ... }
```

Está colidindo com o `ProfileCommon` nativo do .NET.

Comment: ok, vou tentar fazer dessa forma. Obrigado.

Comment: Muito boa a sua resposta cigano, estou até hoje na luta pra construir um perfil, era pra projeto de faculdade. Mais fazer o que me pareçe que o meu perfil não está pegando as configurações do web.Conf, mais tá valendo muito obrigado pelas ajudas oferecidas por aqui.